# Error when installing Scrapy on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, scrapy, pip, easy-install

When I try to install Scrapy on ubuntu 13.04 with the command `sudo easy_install -U Scrapy`, I get the following error:

```
Searching for Scrapy
Reading pypi.python.org/simple/Scrapy/
Best match: Scrapy 0.16.5
Processing Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg
Scrapy 0.16.5 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing scrapy script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for Scrapy
Searching for Twisted>=8.0
Reading pypi.python.org/simple/Twisted/
Best match: Twisted 13.1.0
Downloading pypi.python.org/packages/source/T/Twisted/Twisted-13.1.0.tar.bz2#md5=5609c91ed465f5a7da48d30a0e7b6960
Processing Twisted-13.1.0.tar.bz2
Writing /tmp/easy_install-xYafJF/Twisted-13.1.0/setup.cfg
Running Twisted-13.1.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-xYafJF/Twisted-13.1.0/egg-dist-tmp-ybetxt
twisted/runner/portmap.c:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I also tried `pip install Scrapy` command but again I get the same error `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc`

Could you please help me to install Scrapy on Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: Yes I got the "gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) "

Comment: Official scrapy web site does not recomment this. "Don’t use the python-scrapy package provided by Ubuntu, they are typically too old and slow to catch up with latest Scrapy."

Comment: Yes. It gives the same error. "error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1" "Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-brk/Twisted/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-aiQgfx-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-brk/Twisted"

Comment: Do you have python dev installed?

Comment: Thanks a lot. After installing "python2.7-dev", I succeded to install Scrapy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to install scrapy, you need to have python dev installed first.

Comment: This should be listed as a requirement: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Scrapy if it is a requirement. For me, it certainly was.

Comment: In my case "libxslt1-dev" was also missing

Comment: This isn't helping me.  I have the following error:            python-dev : Depends: libpython-dev (= 2.7.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.4-1~) but it is not going to be installed
N: Ignoring file 'canonical' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'canonical' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Answer (score 17):

For me, I had python dev installed but still wasnt working (was failing when trying to install cryptography) and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073516/failed-to-install-python-cryptography-package-with-pip-and-setup-py) stack overflow post which says to run this command to guarantee all dependencies are installed

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev libxml2-dev`

and that worked for me

Comment: After installing these packages, it worked for me: libssl-doc, libssl-dev, libxml2-dev. I'm still not certain if any of them are superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

Use this : **sudo apt-get install libssl-dev**

before installing scrapy.
and then

**sudo pip install scrapy --force --upgrade**

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue occuring when trying to install Scrapy on a DigitalOcean droplet, it wasn't a library issue, apparently it can happen in low RAM box, you can solve it by combining ionice + pip:

```
sudo ionice -c3 pip install Scrapy
```