# Installing Python Cryptography error

Tags: python, cryptography, pip

When running the `pip install cryptography` I get the following result

```
pip install cryptography
Downloading/unpacking cryptography
Running setup.py egg_info for package cryptography
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/cryptography/setup.py", line 174, in <module>
    "test": PyTest,
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "<string>", line 14, in replacement_run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 254, in find_sources
    mm.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 308, in run
    self.add_defaults()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 332, in add_defaults
    sdist.add_defaults(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 187, in add_defaults
    build_py = self.get_finalized_command('build_py')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in get_finalized_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 117, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py", line 61, in finalize_options
    _build_py.finalize_options(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/command/build_py.py", line 50, in finalize_options
    ('force', 'force'))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 305, in set_undefined_options
    src_cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 117, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/cryptography/setup.py", line 88, in finalize_options
    self.distribution.ext_modules = get_ext_modules()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/cryptography/setup.py", line 65, in get_ext_modules
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import constant_time, padding
  File "cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py", line 49, in <module>
    _ffi = cffi.FFI()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/cryptography/cffi-0.8.6-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/api.py", line 56, in __init__
    import _cffi_backend as backend
ImportError: /tmp/pip-build-root/cryptography/cffi-0.8.6-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/_cffi_backend.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info

writing requirements to pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt

writing pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/cryptography/setup.py", line 174, in <module>

    "test": PyTest,

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "<string>", line 14, in replacement_run

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 254, in find_sources

    mm.run()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 308, in run

    self.add_defaults()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 332, in add_defaults

    sdist.add_defaults(self)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 187, in add_defaults

    build_py = self.get_finalized_command('build_py')

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in get_finalized_command

    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 117, in ensure_finalized

    self.finalize_options()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py", line 61, in finalize_options

    _build_py.finalize_options(self)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/command/build_py.py", line 50, in finalize_options

    ('force', 'force'))

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 305, in set_undefined_options

    src_cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 117, in ensure_finalized

    self.finalize_options()

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/cryptography/setup.py", line 88, in finalize_options

    self.distribution.ext_modules = get_ext_modules()

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/cryptography/setup.py", line 65, in get_ext_modules

    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import constant_time, padding

  File "cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py", line 49, in <module>

     _ffi = cffi.FFI()

  File "/tmp/pip-build-root/cryptography/cffi-0.8.6-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/cffi/api.py", line 56, in  __init__

    import _cffi_backend as backend

ImportError: /tmp/pip-build-root/cryptography/cffi-0.8.6-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/_cffi_backend.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-root/cryptography
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I'm guessing theirs something wrong with some dependencies I'm missing?

When I run the `sudo yum install gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel` to install the dependencies that are required, I get the following result

```
sudo yum install gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.econdc.com
 * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: centos.hyve.com
 * updates: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
Setting up Install Process
Package gcc-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libffi-devel-3.0.5-3.2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package python-devel-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package openssl-devel-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.15.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I'm missing?

Comment: `failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted` implies that the temporary shared object created during the cffi compilation wasn't allowed to be read. This can (apparently) occur with SELinux under certain conditions, although I've never seen it myself. What distribution are you running?

Comment: Any update on this issue? I'm having the same problem, CentOS 6.4

Comment: This ubuntu debian solution worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073516/failed-to-install-python-cryptography-package-with-pip-and-setup-py

Answer (score 8):

Chroot and remounting `/tmp` are unnecessary because you are using `pip` which provides this option (`pip help install`):

```
-b, --build <dir>    Directory to unpack packages into and build in.
```

Simply set that to a directory that does NOT have `noexec`.

Comment: I was in a shared server and couldn't change mount flags. Thank you for pointing out this!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and it happens that the server had **/tmp mounted with noexec.** This was causing all sorts of problems. A way to solve it is to  create a "chroot" environment that contains a "/tmp" directory that allows for file execution:

Follow [this article](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1987/Noexec+and+%7B47%7Dtmp+Troubleshooting#dv_40) for instructions of how to circumvent this.

1. Create a "chroot" environment that contains a "/tmp" directory that allows for file execution:

   mkdir -p /root/chroot /root/tmp
   mount --bind / /root/chroot
   mount --bind /root/tmp /root/chroot/tmp
   chroot /root/chroot
2. "chroot" into the environment you created:

   chroot /root/chroot
3. At this point, you are in the "chroot" environment and can run any commands you need to.

   *Run the instalation*
4. When you are done, type the following commands:

   exit

   umount -l /root/chroot

Answer (score 1):

On some systems, this should work:

```
TMPDIR=~/tmp pip install cryptography
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could mount that volume without noexec flag, by removing it from /etc/fstab or executing `mount -o remount exec /tmp`

fstab solution is less safer, it can be considered a security breach, since anyone could put script on /tmp and execute them.

More info [here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount).