# ReviewBoard pip installation failure

Tags: python, installation, pip, apt-get, review-board

I am trying to install ReviewBoard on 14.04.1-Ubuntu and I get the error below. I have used commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev memcached patch libjpeg-dev
sudo pip install -U pip
sudo easy_install pip
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
sudo pip install ReviewBoard

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 337, in run self.build_extensions()
File "/tmp/pip-build-84i3OO/Pillow/setup.py", line 512, in build_extensions' using --disable-%s, aborting' % (f, f))
ValueError: zlib is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-zlib, aborting
```

---

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-84i3OO/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5lU4Yb-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-84i3OO/Pillow/
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages        
/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Are there any ideas why does it happen and how to solve it?

EDIT

Installed pillow (https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/new-python-dependency-pillow-if-you-get-error-during-update-see-this-post/7900):

```
sudo apt-get install -y libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
sudo pip install pillow
```

Now getting:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -                                                                                                                                                             Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/l                                                                                                                                                             ibffi -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2                                                                                                                                                             .7/c/_cffi_backend.o
c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ffi.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

---

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c 
"import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-hB90D2/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-CCyW5e-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" 
failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hB90D2/cffi/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installed pillow using (https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/new-python-dependency-pillow-if-you-get-error-during-update-see-this-post/7900):

```
sudo apt-get install -y libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
sudo pip install pillow
```

Then ccfi using ([Failed to install Python Cryptography package with PIP and setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073516/failed-to-install-python-cryptography-package-with-pip-and-setup-py)):

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev libssl-dev libpython2.7-dev
sudo pip install cryptography
sudo pip install cffi
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to install `libffi-devel`

```
apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Sometime to fix pip issues its useful to install `build-essential` and `python-dev`

```
apt-get install python-dev && apt-get install build-essential
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. This helped me install the couchapp python tool.

Comment: Also helped to install `sudo pip install rdbtools python-lzf`.

Answer (score 0):

To get Python 2.7 Fabric 1.13 on CentOS 7 working I had to install openssl-devel first.

Complete Error:

```
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-2hTQUe/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mqFBbh-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2hTQUe/cryptography/
```

Solution:

```
sudo yum install -y gcc make openssl openssl-devel
sudo pip install fabric
```