# Install pip3 install quandl -returns Failed cleaning build dir for cryptography

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04

I have following configuration

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Python 3.5
- pip 8.1.1.
- cffi 1.8.3
- IDE PyCharm 2.3 (is not important but just in case)

I have checked the article Python Cryptography package with PIP and setup.py - [Failed to install Python Cryptography package with PIP and setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073516/failed-to-install-python-cryptography-package-with-pip-and-setup-py). Nothing seems to work out.

I have the latest versions of modules (setuptools e.t.c.)

It seems that is trying to build a constructor  and finds some mismatch version

```
          File "/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/src/_cffi_src/utils.py", line 69, in build_ffi
      ffi = FFI()
    File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 59, in __init__
      "version mismatch, %s != %s" % (backend.__version__, __version__)
  AssertionError: version mismatch, 1.5.2 != 1.8.3

       MY SYSTEM HAS 1.8.3 VERSION SEE BELOW
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
Collecting cffi - see http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

  Using cached cffi-1.8.3-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi)
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi
Successfully installed cffi-1.8.3 pycparser-2.16
------------------------------------------------------
```

Just take in mind that I'm not an OS expert
Thank you for your support

**the console command history for pip3 install quandl**

```
pip3 install quandl
Collecting quandl
  Using cached Quandl-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.8 (from quandl)
  Using cached numpy-1.11.2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting more-itertools (from quandl)
Collecting inflection>=0.3.1 (from quandl)
Collecting pyOpenSSL (from quandl)
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-16.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from quandl)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil (from quandl)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1 (from quandl)
  Using cached pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pandas>=0.14 (from quandl)
  Using cached pandas-0.19.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting requests>=2.7.0 (from quandl)
  Using cached requests-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ndg-httpsclient (from quandl)
Collecting cryptography>=1.3.4 (from pyOpenSSL->quandl)
  Using cached cryptography-1.5.2.tar.gz
Collecting pytz>=2011k (from pandas>=0.14->quandl)
  Using cached pytz-2016.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna>=2.0 (from cryptography>=1.3.4->pyOpenSSL->quandl)
  Using cached idna-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools>=11.3 (from cryptography>=1.3.4->pyOpenSSL->quandl)
  Using cached setuptools-28.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi>=1.4.1 (from cryptography>=1.3.4->pyOpenSSL->quandl)
  Using cached cffi-1.8.3-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.4.1->cryptography>=1.3.4->pyOpenSSL->quandl)
Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cryptography ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp79dm6ulvpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/setup.py", line 334, in <module>
      **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
      _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 272, in __init__
      _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 281, in __init__
      self.finalize_options()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 327, in finalize_options
      ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
    File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 181, in cffi_modules
      add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
    File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 48, in add_cffi_module
      execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
    File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 24, in execfile
      exec(code, glob, glob)
    File "src/_cffi_src/build_openssl.py", line 81, in <module>
      extra_link_args=extra_link_args(compiler_type()),
    File "/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/src/_cffi_src/utils.py", line 61, in build_ffi_for_binding
      extra_link_args=extra_link_args,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/src/_cffi_src/utils.py", line 69, in build_ffi
      ffi = FFI()
    File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 59, in __init__
      "version mismatch, %s != %s" % (backend.__version__, __version__)
  AssertionError: version mismatch, 1.5.2 != 1.8.3

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cryptography
  Running setup.py clean for cryptography
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/setup.py", line 334, in <module>
      **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
      _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 272, in __init__
      _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 281, in __init__
      self.finalize_options()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 327, in finalize_options
      ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
    File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 181, in cffi_modules
      add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
    File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 48, in add_cffi_module
      execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
    File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 24, in execfile
      exec(code, glob, glob)
    File "src/_cffi_src/build_openssl.py", line 81, in <module>
      extra_link_args=extra_link_args(compiler_type()),
    File "/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/src/_cffi_src/utils.py", line 61, in build_ffi_for_binding
      extra_link_args=extra_link_args,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/src/_cffi_src/utils.py", line 69, in build_ffi
      ffi = FFI()
    File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 59, in __init__
      "version mismatch, %s != %s" % (backend.__version__, __version__)
  AssertionError: version mismatch, 1.5.2 != 1.8.3

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
Installing collected packages: numpy, more-itertools, inflection, idna, pyasn1, six, setuptools, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, pyOpenSSL, python-dateutil, pytz, pandas, requests, ndg-httpsclient, quandl
  Running setup.py install for cryptography ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qz2rogd_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/setup.py", line 334, in <module>
        **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 272, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 281, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 327, in finalize_options
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
      File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 181, in cffi_modules
        add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
      File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 48, in add_cffi_module
        execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
      File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 24, in execfile
        exec(code, glob, glob)
      File "src/_cffi_src/build_openssl.py", line 81, in <module>
        extra_link_args=extra_link_args(compiler_type()),
      File "/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/src/_cffi_src/utils.py", line 61, in build_ffi_for_binding
        extra_link_args=extra_link_args,
      File "/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/src/_cffi_src/utils.py", line 69, in build_ffi
        ffi = FFI()
      File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 59, in __init__
        "version mismatch, %s != %s" % (backend.__version__, __version__)
    AssertionError: version mismatch, 1.5.2 != 1.8.3

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qz2rogd_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-nrsep1ln/cryptography/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running python on a Raspberry  Pi (linux as well).

After some research I found that the proper libraries may not be installed to then install quandl, the most likely being ssl. Pandas and sklearn might also be necessary (Pandas for sure).

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

pip install pandas

pip install sklearn
```

If after this it still doesn't work, try installing ffi. After all the other stuff, this is the one that worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

THIS is what made it properly do the wheel stuff for cryptography and ciffi.

Using a Pip3 command might work for some, but didn't change the fact for me thatI didn't have the proper tools installed. Hope this works for you.

P.S. I also thought that it had to do with me using virtual environments or the quandl repository but those seemed totally unrelated to the error, as it was actually trying to install, but was just missing the tools it needed.

Comment: The Scikit Learn and pandas are already installed. 
I will try sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
My time is limited. At the first opportunity, I will try it. 
Thanks for the answer. 

PS : In windows it works fine.