# Installing scrapy in Lubuntu using pip install scrapy (or sudo ) and getting the following error

Tags: python-2.7, cryptography, scrapy, pip

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-nExfhn/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-dpob_w-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-nExfhn/cryptography/
```

So I have tried :

1) pip install scrapy (with pip 9.0.1 so no need to update)
2) sudo pip install scrapy (still getting the same error)

I have setup the scrapy framework in Windows environment but in Linux seems different and I also get this Cryptography error.

Comment: You have a problem with cryptography package, read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073516/failed-to-install-python-cryptography-package-with-pip-and-setup-py

Comment: Have you checked non-Python dependencies? [cryptography install pages](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux) mention `sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev`. And [Scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#ubuntu-12-04-or-above) themselves have `sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried looking into each one individually and have spotted the files missing (more commonly its the cryptography packet and the libxml2 .dll ) but the major problem is that if I try to download them individually using sudo apt-get or even pip  it won't complete the download.  I just feel stuck every time I mess with scrapy...