# object has no attribute 'TLSv1_2_METHOD'"

Tags: windows, ansible, credssp

attempting to use CREDSSP with ansible over windows connections, have everything configured and pywinrm[credssp] installed but get thie above error when attempting to run credssp jobs:

```
"changed": false,
"msg": "credssp: 'module' object has no attribute 'TLSv1_2_METHOD'",
"unreachable": true
```

Any idea?

Tried:

[Failed to install Python Cryptography package with PIP and setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073516/failed-to-install-python-cryptography-package-with-pip-and-setup-py)

Requires this command: 
sudo yum install gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel

After that do a pip install --upgrade pywinrm[credssp] ...

Still does not work

Answer (score 1):

In my environment, the problem was pyOpenSSL. When updating pyOpenSSL to a new version using pip, some olders files were left in the directory.

I removed the package via pip uninstall, removed the directory in /usr/lib[64]/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/ and then reinstalled pyopenssl.