# Cryptography not installing even with installing dependencies

Tags: python, cryptography, pip, failed-installation, rhel7

I keep trying to `pip install cryptography` but my build keeps failing with the following errors...What gives? Do I have to do something with openssl or make a custom one...I'm doing this on RHEL 7.

```
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:73274:42: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘_cffi_type_context’
 static const struct _cffi_type_context_s _cffi_type_context = {
                                          ^
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:73274:21: error: parameter ‘_cffi_type_context’ is initialized
 static const struct _cffi_type_context_s _cffi_type_context = {
                     ^
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:73291:11: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘#pragma’
 #  pragma GCC visibility push(default)  /* for -fvisibility= */
           ^
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:73324:11: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘#pragma’
 #  pragma GCC visibility pop
           ^
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:682:9: error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition
 typedef LHASH_OF(CONF_VALUE) Cryptography_LHASH_OF_CONF_VALUE;
         ^
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:682:1: error: parameter name omitted
 typedef LHASH_OF(CONF_VALUE) Cryptography_LHASH_OF_CONF_VALUE;
 ^
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c: At top level:
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:363:18: warning: ‘_cffi_init’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static PyObject *_cffi_init(const char *module_name, Py_ssize_t version,
                  ^
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:607:13: warning: ‘ERR_load_Cryptography_OSRandom_strings’ declared ‘static’ but never defined [-Wunused-function]
 static void ERR_load_Cryptography_OSRandom_strings(void);
             ^
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:608:13: warning: ‘ERR_Cryptography_OSRandom_error’ declared ‘static’ but never defined [-Wunused-function]
 static void ERR_Cryptography_OSRandom_error(int function, int reason,
             ^
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c: In function ‘LHASH_OF’:
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:73324:11: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 #  pragma GCC visibility pop
           ^
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------

Command "/open/usr/local/develop/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ykrnco/cryptography/setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-LnJ81C-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
/open/usr/local/develop/include/site/python2.7/cryptography" 
failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ykrnco/cryptography/
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/22073516/3901060

Comment: Yes I did everything in this solution as well...All dependencies were downloaded