# pip install -U yotta : errors out in Win10

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

When running `pip install -U yotta` I get these messages resulting in an error w/o installation. I am using Python 3.8
Don't know how to resolve the different version requirements for cryptography, pyopenssl, yotta

```
Collecting yotta
  Using cached yotta-0.20.0.tar.gz (130 kB)
...
Collecting cryptography<=2.3,>=2.1.4
  Using cached cryptography-2.3.tar.gz (449 kB)
...
Collecting pyOpenSSL>=0.14; extra == "security"
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-19.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
...
ERROR: pyopenssl 19.1.0 has requirement cryptography>=2.8, but you'll have cryptography 2.3 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: cryptography, pyOpenSSL, requests, PyJWT, wrapt, deprecated, PyGithub, colorama, hgapi, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, pathlib, jsonschema, argcomplete, mbed-test-wrapper, pyyaml, pyelftools, milksnake, appdirs, cmsis-pack-manager, prettytable, sortedcontainers, intervaltree, intelhex, pywinusb, pyusb, pyOCD, argparse, xmltodict, project-generator-definitions, project-generator, valinor, jsonpointer, ntfsutils, yotta
    Running setup.py install for cryptography ... error
...
    build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.c(546): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error+C1083%3A+Cannot+open+include+file%3A+%27openssl%2Fopensslv.h%27%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: After installing cryptography als advised inhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089805/pip-install-cryptography-in-windows I get the same error when installing yotta: ERROR: pyopenssl 19.1.0 has requirement cryptography>=2.8, but you'll have cryptography 2.3 which is incompatible.  and this   Attempting uninstall: cryptography
    Found existing installation: cryptography 2.8
    Uninstalling cryptography-2.8:
      Successfully uninstalled cryptography-2.8
    Running setup.py install for cryptography ... error

Comment: It's a bug in dependencies in `yotta`: it [requires `requests[security]`](https://github.com/ARMmbed/yotta/blob/3ec1819a8497b19f013eb414215beef4e761dcd4/setup.py#L56) and [cryptography>=2.1.4,<=2.3](https://github.com/ARMmbed/yotta/blob/3ec1819a8497b19f013eb414215beef4e761dcd4/setup.py#L62). At the same time [`requests` requires `pyOpenSSL`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/fd13816d015c4c90ee65297fa996caea6a094ed1/setup.py#L105) which [requires `cryptography>=2.8`](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/blob/675534c18ab60517985fdee424837986e58ab260/setup.py#L97). The bug must be fixed in yotta.

Comment: I was unable to install yotta on 64 bit python, but installing yotta on 32 bit python worked ...