# Alpine OS 'pip install cryptography' was hanging several minutes and gave me nothing in return

Tags: python, linux, pip, alpine-linux

When I try to run

```
>>> pip install cryptography
```

It hanging for several minutes so as I can go though setup.py is actually 
missing so how do i get it back?

Thanks! 
[image]

Comment: your formatting is wrong. Please check if there are any dependencies for cryptography.

Comment: check if this works the very first answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073516/failed-to-install-python-cryptography-package-with-pip-and-setup-py

Comment: Note that `cryptography`'s `manylinux1` wheel [is not supported on Alpine](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux) because of musl instead of glibc - try building it from source: `$ sudo apk add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev`, then `$ pip install cryptography --no-binary cryptography`

Comment: even though i showed you in ubuntu it is actually alpine docker container

Comment: @hoefling i did as you said not much changes though

Comment: run `$ pip install cryptography --verbose` and add the output to your answer.

Comment: @hoefling
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/_openssl.c:53885:14: warning: conversion to 'long unsigned int' from 'long int' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion] . this came up.

Comment: This only a warning, shouldn't be the real issue. Please copy the complete output and add it to your question (you can edit the question).