# how to fix error - No module named 'cryptography'

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, cryptography

when I run command `python manage.py runserver` I got an error[image]

also I try to install cryptography on virtual environment by command `pip install cryptography`. It says successfully installed the cryptography with following message. [image]

But still I am not able to avoid the message `No module named 'cryptography'` when I run the server on AWS instance. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: use `python3 manage.py runserver`

Comment: @MousaHalaseh even that syntax also produces the same error

Comment: Could you please run `python3 -m pip install cryptography` and then run the server with `python3 manage.py runserver` as suggested by @MousaHalaseh

Comment: did you add it to your installed apps in settings.py?

Comment: @AlexK I tried `python3 -m pip install cryptography` then `python3 manage.py runserver` this also gives that same message `No module named 'cryptography' `

Comment: @hansTheFranz   I did not realized that  `cryptography ` needed to be add into `INSTALLED_APPS` as it is working fine on localhost with out adding it in. Now, I have added `cryptography` into the installed app but that also giving the same error. also, I am not sure what exactly text would be to add `cryptography` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: what python version do you use in your vertualenv? you can verify by `python --version` after you activate the virtual environment

Comment: @MousaHalaseh its Python 3.4.8

Comment: you may need to install it using pip3, and also make sure you have `python3-dev` installed

Comment: @MousaHalaseh it does not seem to get solved.

Comment: hey guys, I am still struggling with the same issue.