# pip throws "TypeError: deprecated() " error

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, pyopenssl

I am trying to install few packages and started getting an error. Then used multiple commands in ubuntu to update few things but errors are similar

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
or
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
or
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Following is the error sample

```
user@machine:~$ pip install cryptography

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2854, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2445, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2451, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import CommandError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    vendored("cachecontrol")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
.
.
.
.
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "/home/dhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import SSL, crypto
  File "/home/dhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 19, in <module>
    from OpenSSL.crypto import (
  File "/home/dhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 3224, in <module>
    utils.deprecated(
TypeError: deprecated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

I have updated the system with `apt-get install libffi-dev python-dev python3-dev` and
`apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev`  already as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22073516)

Comment: That looks like an [issue](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/issues/1154) with cryptography/pyopenssl packages.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Something got broken down in OpenSSL and no command was working with `pip` afterwards. I was even unable uninstall `pip`.

I removed installation files manually (most likely not a recommended approach) with

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/OpenSSL
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyOpenSSL-22.1.0.dist-info/
```

and reinstalled using `pip3 install pyOpenSSL==22.0.0`. The other version was having some issue as [described here.](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/issues/1154#issuecomment-1268934731)

Comment: I removed OpenSSL from /home/<username>/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages folder and got it solved.

Answer (score 2):

*pip install pyOpenSSL==22.0.0*
works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me too! Ran into this issue on 24.0.0 and going to 22.0.0 solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

For me even uninstall of pyOpenSSL was encountering same error `TypeError: deprecated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`

so first I upgraded pip to 23.0 ,uninstall PyOpenSSL,manually deleted openSSL folder from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages` then installed `PyOpenSSL 20.0.0`, finally issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading `pyOpenSSL` worked for me!

```
pip install pyOpenSSL --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me (Python 3.8.10).

I solved the issue by creating a fresh virtual environment and upgrading pip (from 20.x to latest version as of now 23.1):

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Only after that I installed the other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to dhariya's solution, try removing OpenSSL from .local as well

`sudo rm -rf $home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/`

Answer (score 0):

Despite attempting various commands, I couldn't resolve the problem. However, after restarting my device, pip started functioning correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I know this isn't a good fix but you can just add sudo before the rest of the command. It bypasses the error.

[without sudo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub8yJ.png)

[with sudo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJCs7.png)